SQL max function leetcode 626
In Leetcode 626. Exchange Seats
I write
Select
    (case
        when id%2 != 0 and id = (select max(id) from Seat) then id
        when id%2 =0 then id-1
        else id+1 end) as id,
    student
From Seat
order by id ASC

But what's the difference between
id = (select max(id) from Seat)
and
id = max(id)
It turns out to be wrong when I change it to id = max(id), but I don't understand why. Don't they have the same meaning?
Could someone please explain it to me?

https://dbfiddle.uk/Ml1VCSNz

The id = max(id) version would only run on older versions of MySQL - don't ever do that

All columns in the SELECT clause that do not have an aggregate need to be in the GROUP BY
(also see stackoverflow#6467216)
Therefor  "id = max(id)" is only valid if you add a "group by" clause
select
    (case
        when id%2 != 0 and id = max(id) then id
        when id%2 =0 then id-1
        else id+1 end) as id,
    student
from Seat
group by id, student
order by id ASC

Now with the "id = (select max(id) from seat)" part...
select max(id) from seat
  -- is the same as
select max(id) from seat group by id
  -- and not the same as (a bit stipe down from original sql without the case statement)
select id, student, max(id) from seat group by id, student

